# Generate HTML Report from JTL file in JMETER

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing

1. 

I am unable to generate report from created jtl file, it says, "An Error Occurred : Null!" when generating from jmeter HTML report generator, Is there any other way to generate or any fix for this issue/error.
OR
Can I generate report from other mean of performance testing tools?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Rw3.png)

2.
If I run the same file through non GUI then it doesn't work. I created jtl or CSV file through non GUI mode but nothing save in file with following commands.
jmeter -Jthreads=500 -n -t Anand.jmx -l result500.jtl
or
jmeter -n -t Anand.jmx -l Users-500.jtl
or
jmeter -n -t Anand.jmx -l Users-1500.jtl -e -o C:\Users\opc\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\reports\1500

I have encountered that jtl/csv file doesn't save anything that might be the issue it says null in my first question. but why not saving in jtl/csv file.
Please help me into this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a92es.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. Check whether [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) has any suspicious or clarifying entries
2. Try [generating the dashboard from the command line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) like:

   ```
   jmeter -g /path/to/.jtl/results/file -o /path/to/the/folder/where/dashboard/will/be/generated
   ```
3. I recall that there were problems with generating the dashboard when people used latest Java versions like [Java 17](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/17/), you can try running JMeter using an earlier version, i.e. [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) which is the minimum Java version required to run [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities/)

Comment: I am unable to generate csv/jtl file please check the screen shot.

Comment: Your screenshot is very beautiful, thanks for sharing. Your .jtl file is empty so I don't think it makes sense to try generating the reporting dashboard out of it. You were told to check [`jmeter.log` file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), as long as you're ignoring the suggestions and recommendations unfortunately I'm not able to help further.